# iPad to WCF Services authentication

Tags: wcf, basic-authentication

I am currently working on a project that has an iPad application that uses JSON to call WCF services hosted with IIS. One of the requirements is that the WCF services needs to use IIS Basic Authentication to login. Once the user has been authenticated from the database, a few values need to set to a cookie for return trips to other WCF functions (similar to asp.net session variables).  Is this possible with WCF and using cookies to hold state? If not, any recommended method?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

WCF absolutely supports basic authentication. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733775.aspx has details on this. WCF will then identify this user on all messages that come through.

If you want to implement a customer authorization mechanic, you will need to implement `ServiceAuthorizationManager`. I've recently done something similar where I have iOS clients that use OAuth to authenticate with our services. I have this implemented a `ServiceAuthorizationManager` to determine who they are and what privileges that they have. Might be worth looking into.